# Can you refresh the page when a textbox has been cleared

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I refresh the page when it detects a text input has been cleared (all text deleted).

```
<input type ="search" class="search" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[type='search']").on("input keyup",(e) => {
         $("#results").toggleClass("active",(e.target.value != ""))
    });
</script>

<div class="results" id="results">
```

Comment: Are you asking how to reload the page with JavaScript?  Something else?  Please clarify what problem you have encountered in your code.

Comment: I am asking if you can use `location.reload();` when it detects the text box has been cleared

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use `location.reload();` in JavaScript.  What stops you from trying?  What specifically isn't working as expected in your code?

Comment: My code is working as expected, I am working with PHP in which I need to do a reload when it detects the search text input cleared.

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @ChrisReilly If this answered your question, please mark the answer as correct *(click the checkmark beside the answer)* to close out the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?  Use `location.reload()` when you are ready to actually refresh the page...

```js
$("[type='search']").on("input keyup",(e) => {
   if (e.target.value.length === 0){
      $("#results").html('Rebooting');
      //window.location.reload();
   } else {
      $("#results").addClass("active");
   }
});
```

```css
#results{padding:20px;width:90%;background:lightblue;}
.active{background:pink!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type ="search" class="search" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search">

<div id="results"></div>
```